# Does sharing file/folder/site with an external user result in AD account auto creation and is there a limit?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to share either file/folder/site with an external user.

What I'm trying to understand is whether either of this results in automatic creation of guest account in the AD?

And if it does result in auto creation of AD account, then whether there is a limit to number such users

My research suggests that sharing file and folder doesn't result in AD account creation (and end user can use passcode approach); whereas sharing site necessarily creates a guest account in AD.

And that sharing file/folder has no limit (number of users); where as guest users have a limit of 1:5 (1 existing AD account allows you to create 5 external guest AD accounts)